# mime.quotedprintable having trouble decoding this message

Tags: go, decoding, quoted-printable

I am trying to decode a message which doesn't completely conform to the `Quoted Printable String` idea.

One of the snippets as shown below has an `=` where should be an `=3D` this occurs in a number of places. In fact there are two offences occurring here:

```
------=_Part_7575500_2105086112.1449628640342
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

I'm decoding with the as follows:

```
qpr := quotedprintable.NewReader(msg.Body)
    cleanBody, err := ioutil.ReadAll(qpr)
```

The resulting error is: (complaining about the _ after first =)

```
quotedprintable: invalid hex byte 0x5f
```

How can I fix get this to work please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't just have quoted-printable data, it's part of a MIME multipart message. The `=_` pattern is specifically used because it can never occur in a quoted-printable message.

Use a [`multipart.Reader`](https://golang.org/pkg/mime/multipart/#Reader) to get the contents of each part.

Comment: Ahh.. I've just had a second look. I understand now. There is a container message that is multipart. Then each "part" is quoted-printable... penny drops. Thanks a million!